# add multiple records in table using lambda exprotieoption asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try add multiple records in table. but context.myTbl.AddRnage() not find

```
public void buy(string products)
        {
            var producs1 = products.Split(',');
            List<buyProducs_tbl> records = new List<buyProducs_tbl>();
            //var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Request.Cookies["userID"].Value);
            //var output = MachineKey.Unprotect(bytes, "⇆⇍$n=࿓↖BQ⟳$↢T↥↣v↟➝ZS▶#⇀↚@↟➔S♜u❄4♬♨⇆↟3Xw3$⇀♭↩4ncC⇄↱");
            //string result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output);

            //var bytes2 = Convert.FromBase64String(Request.Cookies["userPhone"].Value);
            //var output2 = MachineKey.Unprotect(bytes, "↯)➶N⇩)~↤R↖↕↦↩cD7↤8m❆yA2@⇅VTE↗↡♟Q8↙2F)U$⇆ix)¢➘⇁↢❅3↶");
            //string result2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output);

            foreach (var i in producs1)
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                buyProducs_tbl setBuyProducs_tbl = new buyProducs_tbl();
                setBuyProducs_tbl.code = rand.Next(10000, 99999).ToString();
                setBuyProducs_tbl.personName="sdf";
                setBuyProducs_tbl.personPhone = "fd";
                setBuyProducs_tbl.products = int.Parse(i);
                setBuyProducs_tbl.status = false;
                records.Add(setBuyProducs_tbl);
            }
            context.buyProducs_tbl.AddRange(records);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

```
Error   7   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MvcApplication2.Models.buyProducs_tbl>' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MvcApplication2.Models.buyProducs_tbl>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
[myProject]\project\MvcApplication2\MvcApplication2\Controllers\HomeController.cs   85  36  MvcApplication2
```

I very search about this bug. can you help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `System.Linq` namespace to access the extension method.

Comment: stystem.linq is imported but the problem not fiexed